# JavaScript only executes once inside php code

Tags: php, javascript, echo, flash

I have a video player which is javascript. I have stuck it inside a php variable and then have attempted to echo it out.  It works perfectly the first time i echo the video. But the second time I echo it the Javascript does not execute.  Any ideas on why that is are helpful thank you

```
 $div = "<div id='mediaplayer'>JW Player goes here</div>";

 $video = "$div <script type='text/javascript' src='jwplayer/jwplayer.js'></script>
                <script type='text/javascript'>
                     jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
                     flashplayer: 'jwplayer/player.swf',
                     file: '$videolocation',
                     image: 'jwplayer/preview.jpg',
                     height: 300,
                     width: 300
                     });
                 </script>";
echo $video;
echo $video;
```

Comment: Do you echo `$div` again as well!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

The values of `id` attributes must be unique within a page. You are reusing yours.

The second script is probably operating on the first div (since it is the first one with the given id).

Comment: Is there any way to use that same id again. or is the only possible to make another div

Comment: No. "The values of id attributes must be unique within a page.". You must use a different id.